# Populate drop down from a properties file using Java

Tags: java, html, drop-down-menu, properties

I have a `test.properties` file which looks like this:

```
1=abc
91=hjk
567=hello
```

I saved this in a`IDEA` root directory. I now wanted to learn how can I populate the same property file in a form of drop down options, which should go like this in my html form:

```
<select>
<option value=1>abc</option>
<option value=91>hjk</option>
.
.
.
</select>
```

so the `key` would be the integer value that should go in `value` and the `key-value` text would go in `option Text`.

I wanted to do this in JAVA using `IDEA` IDE. Any help would be really great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, java is java, regardless of what IDE you use.  Not quite sure what you meant by "root path".  If you mean the project root, than the code below will work as is.  If not, you'll have to update "test.properties" to be a relative or absolute path.

```
        final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder("<select>");
        final Properties props = new Properties();
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream("test.properties");
            props.load(is);
            final Enumeration keyIter = props.propertyNames();
            while (keyIter.hasMoreElements()) {
                final String key = (String) keyIter.nextElement();
                // <option value=1>abc</option>
                buf.append("<option value=").append(key).append(">").append(props.getProperty(key))
                        .append("</option> ");
            }
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
        }
        buf.append("</select>");
        System.out.println(buf.toString());
```

results in

```
<select>
<option value=1>abc</option> 
<option value=567>hello</option> 
<option value=91>hjk</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you user2863942! Is it possible I can do the same coding in a JSP page? as I have the drop down created in a JSP page. How do you suggest me to target that drop down in JSP using this code??

Comment: For a JSP page:
    <%
    --code from above except last line--
    out.println(buf.toString());
    %>

Comment: It doesn't work! if I do the same in my JSP page it vanishes the drop down? can you suggest why is it so?