# How to load dropdown list in html from a properties file?

Tags: javascript, html, properties

If anyone could help 
I have a properties file as below (db.properties) :-

```
1=DEV;
2=NATIVE;
```

and i have to load this value from the properties file into the drop down present in html file 
below is my html file :-

```
<body>
<p> Select the environment </p>
    <br>
    <select name="env">
        <option value="DEV">DEV</option>
        <option value="NATIVE">NATIVE</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

the values from the properties file should come automatically into the drop down present in HTML. Even if a new value is added in the properties file that should be present in the drop down.

Can anyone suggest some code to do the same it would be really helpful

Thank you :)

Comment: You may use Ajax to do that, read the data from db, and update the options.

Comment: @PanwenWang is there any other way to do without using ajax? as i am new to this web part development i have no or less idea about these stuffs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21296000/populate-drop-down-from-a-properties-file-using-java

Comment: @gurvinder372 i have tried this but it was not working for me :(

Comment: why can't you use ajax?

Comment: @gurvinder372 i have no idea on ajax :(

Comment: In that case, read about ajax http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ then try a solution. if not working then share a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to have this file is in json format, but you can download it using XMLHttpRequest (it must be on the same server regarding same-origin policy), parse with split("=") and modify DOM tree by means of appendChild and innerHTML.
If you want to have live changes, you can use setTimeout (first time in DOMContentLoaded, subsequently after modifying SELECT).

Comment: i am sorry, but i need bit simpler solution :( wouldnt this method be bit tough ? as i am a beginner in jsp and html

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps.

```
oo = {};

oo.refreshInterval = 1000;
oo.fileToRequest = 'config.txt';

oo.loadList = function() {
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var lines;
    var select = document.querySelector('select:first-of-type');

    req.onreadystatechange = function() {

      if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
        lines = req.responseText.split('\n');

        while (select.firstChild) {
          select.removeChild(select.firstChild);
        }

        lines.forEach(function(value) {
          var describer = value.split('=')[1];
          var option = document.createElement('option');
          var text = 
            document.createTextNode(
                       describer.substr(0, describer.length - 1)
                     );

          option.appendChild(text);
          select.appendChild(option);
        });
      }

    }

    req.open('get', oo.fileToRequest);
    req.send(null);
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {      
  oo.loadList();
  // Refresh the select box.
  setInterval(oo.loadList, oo.refreshInterval);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it very easily with **`ajax using jQuery`** I have created a demonstration here http://plnkr.co/edit/7PbH8AdQxGc9RGmxslkr?p=preview

> **`Your HTML`**

```
<p> Select the environment </p>
<br>
<select name="env"></select>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
```

> **`Your db.properties file`**

```
1=DEV;
2=NATIVE;
```

> **`js`**

```
$(function(){
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "db.properties"
  }).done(function(data){
    var options = data.split(/\n/);
    $('select[name="env"]').html('');
    for (i=0; i<options.length; i++) {
      console.log(options[i].split('='));
      var optionVal = options[i].split('=').pop().replace(';', "");
      $('select[name="env"]').html('<option value="'+ optionVal +'">'+ optionVal +'</option>');
    }
  })

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't be afraid of using **Ajax**, it's pretty simple:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
            dropdown = document.getElementById("env"),
            lines = [], i, count, line, item;

            xhr.open('GET', '/db.properties');
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                   if (xhr.responseText) {
                      dropdown.innerHtml = "";
                      lines = xhr.responseText.split('/\n|\r\n/');
                      for(i=0,count = lines.length; i < count; i+ = 1){
                          line = lines[i].split('=');
                          item = document.createElement('option');
                          item.text = line[1];
                          item.value = line[0];
                          dropdown.appendChild(item);
                      }                    
                   }
                }
            }
            xhr.send();
    }

</script>
<body>
  <p> Select the environment </p>
  <br>
  <select name="env" id="env">
  </select>
</body>
```